# Is there a way to undo a terminal command?

Tags: shell, command-line, files

I just copied a whole directory into another one using

```
cp ~/local/* ./
```

and actually wanted to type

```
cp ~/local/srl* ./
```

so I'm founding myself with a lot of unnecessary files. I can suppress them by hand but I was wondering, is there a way to undo ANY command on the term?

Comment: If you use another shell update the question, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is no way to undo a command(at least not universal). This is often a problem when users run `rm` with wrong regex, without realising that it covers more files than they would like to remove.

Also, it would really be impossible to implement undoing ANY command from terminal. Imagine command that sends an e-mail, or plays some sound. There is no way to undo these.

Just be happy that you ran `cp`, not `rm`.

As for the future, if you are not moving/removing/copying too many files, `-i` switch will turn it into "interactive" mode, asking for confirmation before each action.

Comment: That would be really great idea to implement! There are songs and movies which I would like to un-watch.

Answer (score 4):

There is no universal way of undoing a command like this. However, providing you have not overwritten any files it's not too difficult to use the list of source files to identify the set that must be removed from the destination:

You accidentally ran this:

> ```
> cp ~/local/* ./
> ```

So to find the set of files to remove, something like this can be used:

```
for SRC in ~/local/*; do DST="${SRC/*\/}"; echo rm "$DST"; done
```

(The `DST="${SRC/*\/}"` strips the path away from the list of files in `~/local/*`, leaving just the filename.) When you're happy it's listed the correct set of files, take out the `echo` from the command and re-run it.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Safe and slow method:**

   This method includes deleting the folders one by one. You can delete the files within the folder of your choice with the command:

   ```shell
   rm -rf folder_name
   ```
2. **Faster method:**

   You have to be cautious since you don't want to accidentally delete the files you need:

   ```shell
   for SRC in ~/local/*; do
       DST="${SRC/*\/}";
       rm "$DST";
   done
   ```

Answer (score -1):

No, in general you cannot undo a terminal command.

In your specific case, you can easily delete all but these specific files:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(srl*)
```

Comment: That would also delete files that existed before the `cp` was performed

Comment: Yes, true, it's not perfect, but you can use additional filters like !(srl*|notdlete1|not*|d[a-Z123])